# Explanation of Parmenides 'perfect' fragment?

Tags: parmenides

From [this site](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Fragments_of_Parmenides), one of Parmenides' fragments is translated:

> Since, then, it has a furthest limit, it is complete
>   on every side, like the mass of a rounded sphere,
>   equally poised from the centre in every direction; for it cannot be greater
>   or smaller in one place than in another.
>   For there is no nothing that could keep it from reaching
>   out equally, nor can aught that is be
>   more here and less there than what is, since it is all inviolable.
>   For the point from which it is equal in every direction tends equally to the limits.

I think Parmenides is arguing that the object on enquiry (i.e. what exists) has to necessarily be uniform and perfect, but I don't see how he reaches this conclusion. It seems like he's using his previous argument that the object of enquiry must be bounded (by bonds and limits), but I can't see the reasoning behind this argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument for the uniformity (or homogeneity, or self-sameness) doesn't follow from the boundedness of *what is*. Parmenides introduces both uniformity and the argument for uniformity in the passage you're citing. The argument is:

> [...] it cannot be greater or smaller in one place than in another.
>   For there is no nothing that could keep it from reaching out equally,
>   nor can aught that is be more here and less there than what is, since
>   it is all inviolable.

The [*Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/parmenides/) presents a paraphrasis of this argument when touching the modal interpretation of Parmenides' *On Nature*, but it's still general enough that it doesn't really lean towards any particular interpretation. Maybe it's a little bit clearer than Burnet's version:

> What must be must be free from any internal variation. Such variation
>   would involve its being something or having a certain character in
>   some place(s) while being something else or having another character
>   in others, which is incompatible with the necessity of its (all) being
>   what it is.